# Is there a way to load vowpalwabbit model and output json_weights() with feature names

Tags: vowpalwabbit

Training a vowpalwabbit model with `--dump_json_weights_include_feature_names_experimental`, and `--invert_hash` enabled outputs a text file containing feature names and feature weights say [sample.txt](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/JSON-export-of-model-weights) which is as expected. However, after saving and loading it from a file, model json_weights() does not output weights in human-readable with feature names similar to `sample.txt`. Is there a way to get feature weights similar to `sample.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is no native way of doing this: "--invert_hash" is only maintaining runtime map from feature names to hashes, but they are not getting saved into model.

Possible workaround:
If you have static features schema, single prediction on example will recover the whole map (without changing the weights):
[image]